# Error iTextSharp Nuget visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, itextsharp, nuget

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Mi solución con varios proyectos funcionaba correctamente, ahora cuando limpio y luego compilo me arroja el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un dato a destacar, es que mi solucion no se encuentra en la ruta que figura en la imagen. Yo tenia mi proyecto en otro lado y lo cambie de lugar, pero siempre compilo a pesar del cambio.
Ya probé desinstalar el paquete iTextSharp, probé instalando versión viejas, y actualizando hasta la ultima también.

Alguien me podrá ayudar indicando que otra cosa podría probar.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Consulta, estás debugeando y te aparece ese aviso? si es así traslada el package a la capeta `/bin` de tu proyecto y debería solucionarse.

Comment: primero limpio la solucion, y luego compilo, cuando compilo. Me tira ese error, no llego ni a poder debugear ese proyecto.

Comment: Prueba esto, quita todos los llamados a ese package (independiente del código de itextsharp) y luego limpia la solución. Una vez que esté limpia agrega el package nuevamente. Me comentas.

Comment: pruebo y comento, Gracias!!!

Comment: Mismo error, incluso elimine la clase que utilizaba ese paquete.

Comment: Amigo, ya que no funcionó prueba lo siguiente. Descarga [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) desde el link y añade la referencia desde el menu `Proyecto/Agregar Referencia`, desde ahí puedes verificar que la ruta también sea correcta. Me comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias harifo por la colaboracion. Mira la unica que me quedo despues de haber probado todo es, crear un nuevo proyecto, agregar todas las dependencias a ese nuevo proyecto y trasladar las carpetas con las clases. Ahora funciona perfecto, elimine el viejo proyecto y le puse el mismo nombre al nuevo. (básicamente lo hice de nuevo). Me queda la bronca de no saber que fue lo que paso.

Comment: @CarlosJR, es posible que el fallo haya sido el ensamblado de versión de la dll, que deberías tenerlo declarado en la 5.5.13, pero que la dll física tuviera otro versionado. Cuando a mí me ha sucedido eso, siempre he revisado las propiedades de la Referencia y los ensamblados en web.config.  Por si el nuevo proyecto te vuelve a dar guerra con las versiones de dll :)